# python.exe crushed while creating numpy array

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory, numpy

I'm trying to execute this code on x32 machine

```
rows=100000
cols=1000

def create_matrix(rows,cols):
    data = (np.random.rand(rows,cols)*100).astype('uint8')
    return data
```

but python.exe is crushed, what it the reason? (I think it's not x32 memory bound? because such array requires only ~100 mb).

Comment: Actually, this will take about 1.6 GB at its highest memory load. How much available memory do you have?

Comment: Do you have a traceback?

Comment: @Wooble no just crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final output only takes about 100 MB. However, the final output isn't the only array you allocate.

```
np.random.rand(rows,cols)
```

This is an array of 100 million float64s. It takes about 800 MB.

```
np.random.rand(rows,cols)*100
```

This is another array of 100 million float64s. It also takes about 800 MB. While it's being computed, both this array and the previous array must remain in memory, for a peak memory usage of about 1.6 GB, 16 times higher than you were expecting.

NumPy doesn't seem to provide a way to directly generate random uint8s. However, you can cut this function's peak memory usage down to about 500 MB by using `numpy.random.randint` to generate int32s instead of float64s and skip a temporary allocation:

```
return np.random.randint(0, 100, (rows, cols)).astype('uint8')
```

If that's still too high, you can generate random numbers in chunks and slice-assign them into a result array, lowering the number of temporary int32s you need to keep in memory at once:

```
data = np.zeros([rows, cols], dtype='uint8')
for chunk_start in xrange(0, rows, rows/10):
    data[chunk_start: chunk_start+rows/10] = (
            np.random.randint(0, 100, (rows/10, cols)))
return data
```

This version should have a peak memory usage of about 140 MB.

Comment: Ok, I understand this, but why python crushed, why it doesn't show some out-of-memory error? (i have 2 Gb of ram on my x32 machine).

Comment: @mrgloom: What do you mean by "crushed"? That's a really vague error report.

Comment: No traceback, console closed and only info is: AppName: python.exe  AppVer: 0.0.0.0  ModName: umath.pyd
ModVer: 0.0.0.0  Offset: 0002b4bb

Comment: and it shows window like this http://telcontar.net/store/archive/CrashGallery/images/crash/a/devstudio_crash.png  but about python.exe

Comment: @mrgloom: Dunno. I'd expect either a MemoryError or horrible swapping.